# Unable to add pallets-contracts-rpc crate

Tags: pallet-contracts

When going through [this tutorial](https://docs.substrate.io/how-to-guides/v3/pallet-design/contracts-pallet/#import-the-dependencies) for adding contracts to the default node template, adding `pallets-contracts-rpc`, the 4th recommended crate to install, I receive various errors. Things compile fine when only the first 3 crates are installed.

```
[package]
name = "node-template-runtime"
version = "4.0.0-dev"
description = "A fresh FRAME-based Substrate runtime, ready for hacking."
authors = ["Substrate DevHub <https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub>"]
homepage = "https://substrate.io/"
edition = "2021"
license = "Unlicense"
publish = false
repository = "https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/"

[package.metadata.docs.rs]
targets = ["x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu"]

[dependencies]
codec = { package = "parity-scale-codec", version = "3.0.0", default-features = false, features = ["derive"] }
scale-info = { version = "2.1.1", default-features = false, features = ["derive"] }

pallet-aura = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.24" }
pallet-balances = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.24" }
frame-support = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.24" }
pallet-grandpa = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.24" }
pallet-randomness-collective-flip = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.24" }
pallet-sudo = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.24" }
frame-system = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.24" }
frame-try-runtime = { version = "0.10.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.24", optional = true }
pallet-timestamp = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.24" }
pallet-transaction-payment = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.24" }
frame-executive = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.24" }
sp-api = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.24" }
sp-block-builder = {  version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.24"}
sp-consensus-aura = { version = "0.10.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.24" }
sp-core = { version = "6.0.0", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.24" }
sp-inherents = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.24"}
sp-offchain = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.24" }
sp-runtime = { version = "6.0.0", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.24" }
sp-session = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.24" }
sp-std = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.24" }
sp-transaction-pool = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.24" }
sp-version = { version = "5.0.0", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.24" }

# Used for the node template's RPCs
frame-system-rpc-runtime-api = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.24" }
pallet-transaction-payment-rpc-runtime-api = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.24" }

# Used for runtime benchmarking
frame-benchmarking = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.24", optional = true }
frame-system-benchmarking = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.24", optional = true }
hex-literal = { version = "0.3.4", optional = true }

pallet-contracts = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.24" }
pallet-contracts-primitives = { version = "6.0.0", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.24" }
pallet-contracts-rpc-runtime-api = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.24" }
pallet-contracts-rpc = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.24" }

# Local Dependencies
pallet-template = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, path = "../pallets/template" }

[build-dependencies]
substrate-wasm-builder = { version = "5.0.0-dev", git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.24" }

[features]
default = ["std"]
std = [
    "codec/std",
    "scale-info/std",
    "frame-executive/std",
    "frame-support/std",
    "frame-system-rpc-runtime-api/std",
    "frame-system/std",
    "pallet-aura/std",
    "pallet-balances/std",
    "pallet-grandpa/std",
    "pallet-randomness-collective-flip/std",
    "pallet-sudo/std",
    "pallet-template/std",
    "pallet-timestamp/std",
    "pallet-transaction-payment-rpc-runtime-api/std",
    "pallet-transaction-payment/std",
    "pallet-contracts/std",
    "pallet-contracts-rpc-runtime-api/std",
    "sp-api/std",
    "sp-block-builder/std",
    "sp-consensus-aura/std",
    "sp-core/std",
    "sp-inherents/std",
    "sp-offchain/std",
    "sp-runtime/std",
    "sp-session/std",
    "sp-std/std",
    "sp-transaction-pool/std",
    "sp-version/std",
]
runtime-benchmarks = [
    "frame-benchmarking/runtime-benchmarks",
    "frame-support/runtime-benchmarks",
    "frame-system-benchmarking",
    "frame-system/runtime-benchmarks",
    "hex-literal",
    "pallet-balances/runtime-benchmarks",
    "pallet-grandpa/runtime-benchmarks",
    "pallet-template/runtime-benchmarks",
    "pallet-timestamp/runtime-benchmarks",
    "sp-runtime/runtime-benchmarks",
]
try-runtime = [
    "frame-executive/try-runtime",
    "frame-try-runtime",
    "frame-system/try-runtime",
    "pallet-aura/try-runtime",
    "pallet-balances/try-runtime",
    "pallet-grandpa/try-runtime",
    "pallet-randomness-collective-flip/try-runtime",
    "pallet-sudo/try-runtime",
    "pallet-template/try-runtime",
    "pallet-timestamp/try-runtime",
    "pallet-transaction-payment/try-runtime",
]
```

```
...
  error[E0308]: mismatched types
      --> /Users/g/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/socket2-0.4.4/src/socket.rs:1777:25
       |
  1777 | from!(net::TcpListener, Socket);
       |                         ^^^^^^ expected struct `Socket`, found `()`
       |
      ::: /Users/g/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/socket2-0.4.4/src/lib.rs:104:16
       |
  104  |             fn from(socket: $from) -> $for {
       |                ---- implicitly returns `()` as its body has no tail or `return` expression

  error[E0308]: mismatched types
      --> /Users/g/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/socket2-0.4.4/src/socket.rs:1778:23
       |
  1778 | from!(net::UdpSocket, Socket);
       |                       ^^^^^^ expected struct `Socket`, found `()`
       |
      ::: /Users/g/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/socket2-0.4.4/src/lib.rs:104:16
       |
  104  |             fn from(socket: $from) -> $for {
       |                ---- implicitly returns `()` as its body has no tail or `return` expression

  error[E0308]: mismatched types
      --> /Users/g/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/socket2-0.4.4/src/socket.rs:1779:15
       |
  1779 | from!(Socket, net::TcpStream);
       |               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected struct `TcpStream`, found `()`
       |
      ::: /Users/g/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/socket2-0.4.4/src/lib.rs:104:16
       |
  104  |             fn from(socket: $from) -> $for {
       |                ---- implicitly returns `()` as its body has no tail or `return` expression

  error[E0308]: mismatched types
      --> /Users/g/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/socket2-0.4.4/src/socket.rs:1780:15
       |
  1780 | from!(Socket, net::TcpListener);
       |               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected struct `TcpListener`, found `()`
       |
      ::: /Users/g/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/socket2-0.4.4/src/lib.rs:104:16
       |
  104  |             fn from(socket: $from) -> $for {
       |                ---- implicitly returns `()` as its body has no tail or `return` expression

  error[E0308]: mismatched types
      --> /Users/g/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/socket2-0.4.4/src/socket.rs:1781:15
       |
  1781 | from!(Socket, net::UdpSocket);
       |               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected struct `UdpSocket`, found `()`
       |
      ::: /Users/g/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/socket2-0.4.4/src/lib.rs:104:16
       |
  104  |             fn from(socket: $from) -> $for {
       |                ---- implicitly returns `()` as its body has no tail or `return` expression

...
```

It seems on the contracts node template that crate is not installed. https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-contracts-node/blob/main/runtime/Cargo.toml

Comment: Perhaps mismatched versions of substrate used? Try from scratch, ensure your lock file has only one commit used for substrate deps

Comment: Did a fresh clone of node template, ensured all are on branch `polkadot-v0.9.24`, added contracts and contracts-rpc-runtime-api to std, and using `cargo check` to validate. Still seeing those errors only when adding `pallet-contracts-rpc`. I've update the Cargo.toml above

Comment: Were you able to solve this? 
I'm having the exact same error

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're adding the `pallet-contracts-rpc` dependency to the runtime (`runtime/Cargo.toml`). It should only be added to the node (`node/Cargo.toml`) though.

The reason is that everything under `runtime/` will be run in an isolated `no_std` sandbox mode in WebAssembly, whereas the RPC endpoints are very much exposed to the outside networking world.

There is some glue between sandbox and node (you can think of the node as a client running the runtime within). This glue code is the `pallet-contracts-rpc-runtime-api`.

The tutorial has been updated by now (the link from the top post also no longer works). I'm not sure what the tutorial was referring to before, but the current one under https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/work-with-pallets/contracts-pallet/ contains the correct instructions.