# Error when add pallet-contracts in substrate : no matching package named `pallet-contracts-rpc-runtime-api` found location

Tags: polkadot, substrate-node-template, substrate-contracts-node

i want to add pallet-contracts into substrate on branch but i faced errro .

[Repository](https://github.com/dortajkianoush/substrate_dex)

i will tell you step by step what i did :

**Step One : Add Depency Pallets**

```
pallet-contracts = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git",  " branch" = "polkadot-v0.9.35" }
pallet-contracts-primitives = { version = "7.0.0", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git",  " branch" = "polkadot-v0.9.35" }
pallet-contracts-rpc-runtime-api = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", " branch" = "polkadot-v0.9.27" }
```

**Step Two : Add Pallets Config**

```
   parameter_types! {
    pub TombstoneDeposit: Balance = deposit(
        1,
        <pallet_contracts::Pallet<Runtime>>::contract_info_size()
    );
    pub DepositPerContract: Balance = TombstoneDeposit::get();
    pub const DepositPerStorageByte: Balance = deposit(0, 1);
    pub const DepositPerStorageItem: Balance = deposit(1, 0);
    pub RentFraction: Perbill = Perbill::from_rational(1u32, 30 * DAYS);
    pub const SurchargeReward: Balance = 150 * MILLICENTS;
    pub const SignedClaimHandicap: u32 = 2;
    pub const MaxValueSize: u32 = 16 * 1024;
    // The lazy deletion runs inside on_initialize.
    pub DeletionWeightLimit: Weight = AVERAGE_ON_INITIALIZE_RATIO *
     BlockWeights::get().max_block;
    // The weight needed for decoding the queue should be less or equal than a fifth
    // of the overall weight dedicated to the lazy deletion.
    pub DeletionQueueDepth: u32 = ((DeletionWeightLimit::get() / (
        <Runtime as pallet_contracts::Config>::WeightInfo::on_initialize_per_queue_item(1) -
        <Runtime as pallet_contracts::Config>::WeightInfo::on_initialize_per_queue_item(0)
     )) / 5) as u32;

    pub Schedule: pallet_contracts::Schedule<Runtime> = Default::default();
}

impl pallet_contracts::Config for Runtime {
    type Time = Timestamp;
    type Randomness = RandomnessCollectiveFlip;
    type Currency = Balances;
    type Event = Event;
    type RentPayment = ();
    type SignedClaimHandicap = SignedClaimHandicap;
    type TombstoneDeposit = TombstoneDeposit;
    type DepositPerContract = DepositPerContract;
    type DepositPerStorageByte = DepositPerStorageByte;
    type DepositPerStorageItem = DepositPerStorageItem;
    type RentFraction = RentFraction;
    type SurchargeReward = SurchargeReward;
    type WeightPrice = pallet_transaction_payment::Module<Self>;
    type WeightInfo = pallet_contracts::weights::SubstrateWeight<Self>;
    type ChainExtension = ();
    type DeletionQueueDepth = DeletionQueueDepth;
    type DeletionWeightLimit = DeletionWeightLimit;
    type Call = Call;
    /// The safest default is to allow no calls at all.
    ///
    /// Runtimes should whitelist dispatchables that are allowed to be called from contracts
    /// and make sure they are stable. Dispatchables exposed to contracts are not allowed to
    /// change because that would break already deployed contracts. The `Call` structure itself
    /// is not allowed to change the indices of existing pallets, too.
    type CallFilter = Nothing;
    type Schedule = Schedule;
    type CallStack = [pallet_contracts::Frame<Self>; 31];
}
```

**Step two : Add runtime api**

```
   impl pallet_contracts_rpc_runtime_api::ContractsApi<Block, AccountId, Balance, BlockNumber>
    for Runtime
{
    fn call(
        origin: AccountId,
        dest: AccountId,
        value: Balance,
        gas_limit: u64,
        input_data: Vec<u8>,
    ) -> ContractExecResult {
        let (exec_result, gas_consumed) =
            Contracts::bare_call(origin, dest.into(), value, gas_limit, input_data);
        match exec_result {
            Ok(v) => ContractExecResult::Success {
                flags: v.flags.bits(),
                data: v.data,
                gas_consumed: gas_consumed,
            },
            Err(_) => ContractExecResult::Error,
        }
    }

    fn get_storage(
        address: AccountId,
        key: [u8; 32],
    ) -> pallet_contracts_primitives::GetStorageResult {
        Contracts::get_storage(address, key)
    }

    fn rent_projection(
        address: AccountId,
    ) -> pallet_contracts_primitives::RentProjectionResult<BlockNumber> {
        Contracts::rent_projection(address)
    }
}
```

but it show me this error :

```
no matching package named `pallet-contracts-rpc-runtime-api` found location searched: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git
```

whats the problem ? how can i solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the `pallet-contracts-rpc-runtime-api` from the runtime, it doesn't have to be there anymore.

See this previous answer from [StackExchange for more information](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/4182/2762):

> The reason is that everything under runtime/ will be run in an isolated no_std sandbox mode in WebAssembly, whereas the RPC endpoints are very much exposed to the outside networking world.

I recommend you to check [the code of a parachain that runs in rococo and has the pallet-contract in it](https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus/tree/master/parachains/runtimes/contracts/contracts-rococo), if you want to use it as a guide about how to add the pallet.