# how to add contract pallet into polkadot-v0.9.31

Tags: polkadot, substrate-node-template, smart-contract

I want to add `contract` pallet into `polkadot-v0.9.31`, but there is no tutorial in [official documentation][1], and it seems that `pallet-contracts-rpc-runtime-api` not exists.
How can I add `contract pallet` into `polkadot-v0.9.31`?

cheers
[1]: https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/

Answer (score 1):

`pallet-contracts-rpc-runtime-api` doesn't have to be in the runtime anymore, see this previous StackExchange question: [Error when add pallet-contracts in substrate : no matching package named `pallet-contracts-rpc-runtime-api` found location](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/6915/error-when-add-pallet-contracts-in-substrate-no-matching-package-named-pallet/6924#6924).

And as suggested there use the [Contracts Rococo parachain](https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus/blob/master/parachains/runtimes/contracts/contracts-rococo/README.md) as an example of how to add the pallet contracts: check how to import it in the [Cargo.toml](https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus/blob/master/parachains/runtimes/contracts/contracts-rococo/Cargo.toml#L50), in the [runtime](https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus/blob/master/parachains/runtimes/contracts/contracts-rococo/src/lib.rs) of your node and the [configuration](https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus/blob/master/parachains/runtimes/contracts/contracts-rococo/src/contracts.rs) needed for the pallet contracts.

Comment: Thanks! I have added contract pallets in to my template-node.

Comment: but when I deploy flipper contract and execute flip() function, it returns ‘contracts.OutOfGas‘，do you know how to fix it?

Comment: That's related to the  Weights v2, how are you interacting with flipper? Check this reponse https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/7275/2762

Comment: or this previous SE answer: https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/7368/2762

Comment: flip() returns ‘contracts.OutOfGas‘ and read() doesn't response. I have tried contract-UI. Using https://contracts-ui.substrate.io, I can't click "next" button，and using weightv1--contracts-ui.netlify.app and when I click "upload and instantiate" button, it returns "InstantiateWithCode error". I install local contract-ui and it still don't work. I have to use my local node template rather than contracts-node, maybe there are other methods? Thanks a lot!

Comment: To see if is a problem with your contract. Does it work if you deploy/interact using cargo-contract? take a look how to interact here: https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/smart-contracts/develop-a-smart-contract/#deploy-and-test-the-smart-contract